# Vi isn't handling curly braces in my perl script correctly

Tags: regex, perl, vim, vi, curly-braces

Vi gets messed up with my perl script! 
While `{` at the end of the code matches none of the closing curly brackets, `{`s at the end of the lines 27 and 28 match the same `}` at 30.

Here is the screen video of how Vi treats my script behavior.

[image: mini-screencast demonstrating the issue]
<sub>(source: [abbasinasab.com](http://www.abbasinasab.com/data/uploads/sc-4.gif))</sub>

Here is also my troublemaker piece of code:

```
#CODE                                                                                                               
while ($data =~ m{                                                                                                      
    ^foo_\s+ $X \s* \{                                                                                                  
        ( (?: [^{}]+ | \{(?1)\} )* )                                                                                    
    \}                                                                                                                  
}mgx)                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                       
    my $Y = $1;                                                                                                         
    next if $Y !~ m{                                                                                                    
        bar_$Z \s* \{                                                                                                   
            ( (?: [^{}]+ | \{(?1)\} )*? )                                                                               
        \}                                                                                                              
    }mx;                                                                                                                

    my $DO = $1;                                                                                                        
    #CODE                                                                                                               
}
```

My questions are:

1. How and Why couldn't Vi handle the curly braces in this situation.
2. How can I rewrite my ugly-written piece of code to avoid this confusion for Vi.

Comment: You can use any delimiter for the `m`. Like: `seq 350 | perl -lanE 'say $_ if m 1331'` but it is recommented to use only punctuation characters, like: `/` `@` or pairs `()` `[]` `<>` and like.

Comment: Perl is extremely hard to parse, especially with the `/gmx` modifiers (particularly the `/x` modifier).

Comment: Perl is actually undecidable to parse. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393

Comment: If you think this is a bug in how vim-perl handles those braces (and it very well could be), please submit a ticket to the vim-perl project: https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl  vim-perl is where we curate the Perl-related Vim files that get folded back into the Vim distribution.  You might also try using the syntax files from the vim-perl project and see if the more current versions are more robust than the ones that came with whatever version of Vim you're using now.

Comment: Um, sorry for the off-topic question but, what did you use to create the little screencast? :P

Comment: Complexity overdose.

Answer (score 4):

There are two pieces of functionality in Vim that can be fooled by complex syntaxes:

- The `'matchpairs'` highlighting and jumping uses an internal heuristic. This can be slightly influenced (cp. `:help cpo-M`):

```
:set cpo+=M
```

With this, the `%` correctly jumps to the expected closing brace (unless you have a plugin like *matchpairs.vim* override the `%` command). Also note that the `'cpoptions'` setting is global, so this may adversely affect *other* filetypes.

- The syntax highlighting is regexp-based. As such, it will fail with corner cases and complex syntaxes (like C++ and Perl) which cannot be faithfully modeled with regular expressions (but require a custom parser).

---

In general, I would avoid rewriting the code just so that the editor will be happy. Other people may use different editors, and soon the code gets hugely distorted with various such "workarounds". The only exception is when the code is obviously complex and cumbersome, and general readability would improve from a restructuring.